# Regular Expression (regex) match of base64_decode concatenated using PHP

Tags: php, regex, base64, exploit

So i've been trying to build a regex for the past couple hours and i'm starting to go crazy in thinking if this is even possible or worth wild.

I have a script that scans PHP files checking MD5 sum for known malicious files, and certain strings.  Most recently i've come across files where instead of using base64_decode in the PHP file, they are using variables and concatenating it so the scanner doesn't pick it up.

As an example here's the latest one I found:

```
$a='bas'.'e6'.'4_d'.'ecode';eval($a
```

So because the scanner searches for base64_decode this file wasn't picked up as they are using PHP to concatenate base64_decode in a variable, and then call the variable.

Forgive me because i've just started with regex, but is it even possible to search for something like this using regex?  I mean, I understand and was able to get a regex that would match that exact one, but what about if they used this instead:

```
$a='b'.'ase'.'64_d'.'ecode';eval($a
```

It wouldn't be picked up because the regex was looking for ' then b then a, etc etc.

I've already added

```
(eval)\(\$[a-z]
```

To send me an email as a notice to check the file, i'll have to let it run for a couple days and see how many false positives show up, but my main concern is with the base64_decode

If someone could please shed some light on this for me and maybe point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp:

```
b\W*a\W*s\W*e\W*6\W*4\W*_\W*d\W*e\W*c\W*o\W*d\W*e
```

It searches for `base64_decode` with any non-alphanumeric characters interspersed.

Comment: You have typo, should be : `b\W*a\W*s\W*e\W*6\W*4\W*_\W*d\W*e\W*c\W*o\W*d\W*e`